# Retrieve fields with space in the name through javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a problem in retrieving fields stored in MongoDB using a javascript script.

The db has been stored automatically after a web-crawl. Here's an example of an entry:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51ed0b2e12fd5629bf380355"),
        "title" : "Robert",
        "extraction" : {
                "infobox" : [
                        {
                                "given name" : {
                                        "region" : "Germanic",
                                        "articles" : "Robert",
                                        "pronunciation" : "{{IPAc-en|ˈ|r|ɒ|b|ər|t}}",
                                        "related names" : "Rob, Robbie, Robin, Rupert, Bob, Bobby, Bert, Rahbert",
                                        "name" : "Robert",
                                        "gender" : "Male",
                                        "meaning" : "\"fame-bright\""
                                }
                        }
                ]
        }
}
```

I have to retry all the couples *title* - *related names*. I wrote this javascript:

```
db = connect("localhost:27017/Test");


var nameCursor = db.Test.find({"extraction.infobox.given name.related names":{$exists:true}},{"title":1,"extraction.infobox.given name.related names":1});

nameCursor.forEach(
  function(myDoc) {
      print(myDoc.title+" "+extraction.infobox.given name.related names );
  }
);

quit();
```

which of course is not working when it has to print because of the space in `given name` and `related names` fields. 
Is there a way to escape the space, or at least to print the *infobox* json string, which I will eventually parse?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I already know that next time I will have to substitute the space in the field keys with `_`. The extraction takes a long time, and now I quite in a hurry :)

**Edit after Sammaye comment**

Using `extraction.infobox['given name']['related names']`, it gives me the error

```
 JavaScript execution failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'related names' of undefined at names.js:L14
```

Of course, if I use `extraction.infobox['given name']` it prints

```
Robert undefined
```

Comment: `extraction.infobox['given name']['related names']`

Comment: It is not working (see edit), could it be because of the array nature of `infobox`?

Comment: Nah arrays and objects are both objects and can be accessed the same, most likely your structure or your query is not working as you expect

Comment: The query is working in mongodb console, I can retrieve what I need. Is there any solution to exploit this to retrieve all I need, even without using javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you who stayed tuned, I modified the function in the loop to:

```
 function(myDoc){
   print(myDoc.title+" "+JSON.stringify(myDoc.extraction.infobox));
 }
```

Now I will have to clean a little bit the output (just a little bit, the projection operator used to build the cursor has done most of the job), but it worked!!